# Table not Alter

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I want to add Unique query in combination of Two column.I am using this but this is not able make Unique. Please help Any help would be apperciated.

```
updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NewsData (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NewsId TEXT  ,NewsValue TEXT,Title TEXT,Region INTEGER)"];
    update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update_stmt, -1, &addStatement, NULL);
    sqlite3_step(addStatement);
    sqlite3_reset(addStatement);


    updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ALTER TABLE NewsData ADD UNIQUE (NewsId, Region)"];
    update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update_stmt, -1, &addStatement, NULL);
    sqlite3_step(addStatement);
    sqlite3_reset(addStatement);
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has very limited `ALTER TABLE` support; the only alterations it supports are `ADD COLUMN` and `RENAME`.

To perform more advanced alterations, you will need to create a new table with the new schema, do an `INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;` to copy the data, drop the old table, then rename the new table to the old name.

Though in this case, you can also add a unique index using the [`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX`](http://sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) command.